# Can an entry have multiple authors?

Tags: entry, author

I'm trying to create a multi user blog, where multiple authors can edit the same entry. Is this possible with Craft CMS? Is there a way to assign multiple authors to an entry? I only managed to assign one user as an author.

Comment: I second this, multiple authors for one entry would be a very useful addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there can only be one author. But what you can do is to add one or more custom [user fields](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/users-fields) to your entry type and use these to assign different type of users to your entry (all contributing authors, photographers, etc.).

Set user privileges like Douglas describes in [his answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4658/125), to allow multiple authors to edit entries in your section.

Comment: Thanks Douglas and carlcs for your answers and nicael for editing the initial question. I think a native solution for multiple authors would make a good feature request for Craft CMS.

Comment: Hmm.. I think it's rather unusual for Craft entries / elements to have multiple authors. But yeah if there's multiple people involved it's actually not so nice to have the default field visible after adding custom "replacement fields". I have a similar problem with dates, where I added multiple custom date fields to entries and the publish / expire dates are rather confusing to the client.

Comment: What you could do is to use Lindsey's [Control Panel CSS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) to hide the default author field in the CP, @JayBerg. You could then add a new tab for meta data (authors, categories, etc.) to separate it from the content.

Comment: I have also used the approach which CarlCS illustrates here - works very well!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there can only be one author. You would have to create a `user group`, assign the editors/users to the group and then in the group settings, 'authorize users to edit entries in that section', and 'allow users to edit entries by other authors'.